# All outgoing mail is marked as spam by gmail

Tags: ubuntu, email, smtp, vps, spam

All my emails sent from my SMTP server (created with VespaCP) is being marked as spam by gmail. DNS and DKIM is setup correctly. By using isnotspam.com, I have figured out that the reason is spamassasin giving them a score of 3.7. 
Here is the report:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin 3.4.1 (2015-04-28)

Result: ham (non-spam) (03.7points, 10.0 required)

pts rule name description
---- ---------------------- -------------------------------


* 3.5 BAYES_99 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99 to 100%
* [score: 1.0000]
* -0.0 SPF_HELO_PASS SPF: HELO matches SPF record
* -0.0 SPF_PASS SPF: sender matches SPF record
* -0.0 RP_MATCHES_RCVD Envelope sender domain matches handover relay domain
* 0.2 BAYES_999 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99.9 to 100%
* [score: 1.0000]
* 0.1 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message
* -0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from author's
* domain
* 0.1 DKIM_SIGNED Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily
* valid
* -0.1 DKIM_VALID Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
X-Spam-Status: Yes, hits=3.7 required=-20.0 tests=BAYES_99,BAYES_999,
DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,HTML_MESSAGE,RP_MATCHES_RCVD,
SPF_HELO_PASS,SPF_PASS autolearn=no autolearn_force=no version=3.4.0
X-Spam-Score: 3.7
```

I have no clue exactly what is triggering this, I am trying to send verification email with nodejs, but BAYES_99 BODY is triggered regardless of how I send the email or what it contains.

Comment: Huh? It says it's not spam. "Result: ham (**non-spam**) (03.7points, 10.0 required)"

Comment: Yes, but as stated in the question, gmail still marks it as spam, and I thought maybe spamassasin had something to do with it.

Comment: Gmail typically indicates why something's flagged as spam (if a bit vaguely) and has useful header info. Why not look at that instead of a totally separate service that has nothing to do with Gmail? To my knowledge, Gmail doesn't use SpamAssassin at all.

Comment: Have you verified you are not on a blacklist using [mxtoolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx) and are you sure your SMTP server is authorized in your SPF record (again, check [mxtoolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/spf.aspx))

Comment: @ceejayoz Gmail just tells me it was detected as spam by their filters. How do you view the header info?

Comment: It's not on any blacklist, and mxtoolvox says it's all ok.

Answer (score 3):

> BAYES_99 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99 to 100%
>   BAYES_999 BODY: Bayes spam probability is 99.9 to 100%

When the actual email messages you send are (indistinguishable from) Spam they are still likely to get classified as such. Regardless of how well configured your mail server is.

You will need to check and see the resulting messages (bodies) and change whatever you use to generate your mail messages. Your problem can be as simple as that your  generated HTML is a single line without any line breaks.

Answer (score 3):

Gmail does not use spamassassin. Moreover, Bayes score is not a general metric, it strictly depends on the local bayes database.

This test isn't helpful in debugging the issue.

Probably Gmail is not acting for something related to this specific message, it may be a reputation issue. You may get some hints directly from Google by subscribing to the Google postmaster console:
https://postmaster.google.com

Comment: The 1 million dollar question is how to solve problems with Gmail regardless of any rules, since postmaster has no data and still expresses a reputation for a domain. Also Gmail has no support or contact whatsoever so pretty much they just blacklist whole domains with no way to fix the problem or knowing exactly what is bothering them